# Change from global to local

Tags: python

I am working in global, however when I enter edit mode I would like to change to LOCAL. The python code is missing something.

> bpy.context.scene.type = 'LOCAL'

Comment: The transform orientation you describe is a property of the [SpaceView3D](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.transform_orientation). If you are using operators in your script look at passing the [`constraint_orientation`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=constraint_orientation#bpy.ops.transform.transform) parameter available in many operators. It would be better to share your script and explain the final result you want to achieve, you may be better off using a matrix with bmesh operators.

Answer (score 1):

On the 3D header, there is a button where you can change it from Global to Local.
[image: Local]

Hope that answers your question :)

Comment: in python script please.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure if that was what you wanted.  Unfortunately, I don't know python :) :(  Sorry